# Property Doesn't Exist on Typescript Interface

Tags: javascript, interface, typescript

I have a custom "Enum" interface that that has a value and a description. I've defined an my enum interface like this-

```
module App {
  export interface IMyEnum {
    [index: string]: IMyEnumValue;
  }

  export interface IMyEnumValue {
      value: any;
      text: string;
  }
}
```

And my enums like this-

```
/// <reference path="./enums.interface.ts"/>

module App {
  export const StatusEnum: IMyEnum = {
    Normal: { value: 100, text: 'Normal' },
    Overdue: { value: 200, text: 'Overdue' },
    Critical: { value: 300, text: 'Critical' }
  }
}
```

But the typescript compiler is complaining that "Normal" does not exist on type IMyEnum.

```
let statusCode = StatusEnum.Normal.value;
```

Is there anyway to do this without defining an `IStatusEnum` interface? I think that would be over-engineering.

Comment: Try putting `Normal` in `"Normal"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you cast `StatusEnum` to `IMyEnum`, you actually lose type info, leaving you only with an indexer: `[index: string]: IMyEnumValue`

Option 1: use strings

```
let statusCode = StatusEnum["Normal"].value;
```

You'll lose compile-time safety on enum names (e.g. `StatusEnum["normal"].value` will give a runtime error).

Option 2: get rid of `IMyEnum` and let the compiler infer the type.

```
  export const StatusEnum = {
    Normal: { value: 100, text: 'Normal' },
    Overdue: { value: 200, text: 'Overdue' },
    Critical: { value: 300, text: 'Critical' }
  }

let statusCode = StatusEnum.Normal.value;
```

That way you'll have type safety and autocompletion.

Comment: Guess I can't have my cake and eat it too. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, the 2nd option is pretty good in terms of type safety. What is your main reason to declare `IMyEnum`?

Comment: Trying to add some sense to some old code I've adopted. I would have liked to have each object bound by the same rules through the compiler than loosely abiding to them in convention. But this is good enough.